# Infinite loop repository symfony2 fos user bundle

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, fosuserbundle, symfony-forms

I just override the `UserManager.php` of the FOSUser Bundle of Symfony2, most particularly the updateUser function (I have the last version of the bundle and last version of the framework).

Here is the function (with the debug parts) :

```
<?php
    /**
     * Updates a user.
     *
     * @param UserInterface $user
     * @param Boolean       $andFlush Whether to flush the changes (default true)
     */
    public function updateUser(UserInterface $user, $andFlush = true, $form = false)
    {

        $this->updateCanonicalFields($user);
        $this->updatePassword($user);

        if ($form !== false) {
            $em = $this->objectManager;

            $user->setStatus($em->getRepository('BirdOfficeBundle:Status')->find(1));

            $language = $em->getRepository('BirdOfficeBundle:Language')->getLanguage(1);

            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($language);die();

            //$user->setLanguage($em->getRepository('BirdOfficeBundle:Language')->find(1));
            //$user->setType($em->getRepository('BirdOfficeBundle:Type')->find(1));

            echo '<pre>';var_dump($user);die();
        }

        $this->objectManager->persist($user);
        if ($andFlush) {
            $this->objectManager->flush();
        }
    }
?>
```

What I want to do with this function is to call it from my `RegistrationController.php` (registerAction method) after the submit of my register form.

The problem is the following :

When I set my status, it's working very well. When I try to use the find method from other repositories (like Langue, Type, or whatever), my web browser crash.

I tried to use it in another controller, for test, and it works very well.

So, what can be the problem ?

By the way, I tried to use findAll or personal queries, but it crashes too.

I checked my `dev.log` file, and there is no `event.ERROR` in it.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs to see why the request crashed?

Comment: Hum, you are right, I must do that.
Do I have to check the log in Symfony2 files (if there are logs inside) or my MAMP Apache logs ?

Comment: Check both your MAMP apache logs and in the Symfony project check the app/logs folder

Comment: I do that, give you the details in few minutes !

Comment: You should be getting errors logged in one of those two places, make sure you are accessing your symfony project using the app_dev.php entry point and it should display errors in the debug toolbar, which you can click into to investigate further

Comment: Your browser (client side) shouldn't crash if there is a PHP-related error (server side). Maybe the output of `var_dump($language)` is too big to handle? Try to use the new VarDmper Component: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/introduction.html

Comment: I try that and I get back to you the result after.
By the way, the setter functions doesn't work too (not only the var_dump one)

Comment: A browser crash is a different problem. Bad code in Symfony2 should throw an Exception (or another error/warning). What's your real problem; a browser crash? In that case, please update your question with browser details.

Comment: @StephanVierkant
I don't think that my problem is the browser crash. Firefox and even Chrome crash, so, it's a Symfony code (or structure) problem.
I'm installing var_dumper now, I will give you back the details

Comment: Hum, this is really strange. The var_dumper works very well, but the result is really little (I was looking for a one row find only)

Comment: @g4briel You mentioned 'infinite loop' in the title. That's a very likely reason for a browser crash. What does `getLanguage()` do?

Comment: I'm french, so maybe I made a mistake using "infinite loop". It's just that my page refresh never ends. getLanguage returns a language object. I already used it in an other controller and it works very well.
But I can see a difference between my getStatus var_dumper and the getLanguage one.
Status :
`Status {#722 ▼
  -id: 1
  -name: "Cr&eacute;&eacute;"
}`
Language :
`array:1 [▼
  0 => Language {#737 ▼
    -id: 1
    -status: Status {#742 ▶}
    -image: null
    -traductions: PersistentCollection {#787 ▶}
    -name: "Fran&ccedil;ais"
  }
]`
Do you see smthg wrong ? It's not the same structure

Comment: I think overriding `UserManager.php` is a bad practise. However, you can override forms, templates  and controllers (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md). I think you want an EntityListener to add a default language or status. Please read the documentation of both FOSUserBundle and Symfony2/Doctrine.

Comment: I read this https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md several times of course.
Thank you for the EntityListener part, I will take a look. But what's really strange is that Langue, Type, and others work very well in the DefaultController.php of my bundle. Anyway, I will continue my search ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a solution.
I removed the `find()` calls for my own functions (`getStatus`, `getLanguage`, `getType`) and I put a try/catch call inside.

Now, it works really good !

Here is the code for `Acme/AcmeBundle/Repository/LanguageRepository.php`

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AcmeBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class LanguageRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getLanguage($id) {
        $db = $this
                ->createQueryBuilder('l')
                ->andWhere('l.id = :id')
                ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ;

        try {
            $language = $db->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
        } catch (\Doctrine\Orm\NoResultException $e) {
            $language = null;
        }
        return $language;
    }
}
```

And the code of my `UserManager.php` method :

```
<?php

    $language = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Language')->getLanguage(1);
    if (is_null($language)) {
       $language = 1;
    }
    $user->setLanguage($language);
```

After that, I launch a `php app/console cache:clear`

Thank you very much ;)

Gabriel